# Using a for loop to insert list array into a html page table

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on building a website page where a table will be displayed to show the ranking, name, address, and phone # of restaurants.  First I am trying to write a for loop that will insert the sample array list into the table.  The heading of the table and style were working fine but somehow I could not insert the array list into the table body.  The code is as followed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="static/css/style2.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>The Top Ten Restaurants in {{zip_code}}</title>
  </head>

  <body>


    `<h1>Yelp Rating System</h1>`



    <h2>Top 10 restaurants in zip code: {{zip_code}}</h2>

    <table id="table" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Rank</th>
                <th>Restaurant Name</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td> 
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

        <!--    <tr>            
                <td><a href="{{ url_for('restaurant', restaurant_info=11355 )}}">                   Restaurant x</a></td>
            </tr> 
        -->

        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script>
    var array = 
    [
        ["1","Kiku", "555 5th ave, New York, NY 11355", "212-111-2222"],
        ["2","Yamoto", "444 6th ave, New York, NY 11355", "212-888-9999"]
    ],
        var table = document.getElementById("table");

    for(var i = 0; i <table.rows.length; i++)
    {
        for(var j = 0; j< table.rows[i].cells.length; j++)
        {
            table.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML = array[i - 1][j];
        }
    }

    /*for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        var newRow = table.insertRow(table.length);
        for (var j = 0; j< array[i].length; j++)
        {
            var cell = newRow.insertCell[j];
            cell.innerHTML = array[i]][j];
        }
    }*/
    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

I also will like to ask if data is successfully inserted into the table, how can I make column 1 of the table into a hyperlink for another HTML script.

Comment: Have the browser's web inspector open so that you can see any potential error(s). At first glance, you are likely having trouble here: `array[i - 1][j]` ... what happens (or I should say, what is the index reference) if `i = 0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of mistakes in your original code, but i make that working as

1) Use of comma(,), instead of semicolon(;) after array declaration
2) There are total 3 rows(including table head), so loop through only last 2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<link href="static/css/style2.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<title>The Top Ten Restaurants in {{zip_code}}</title>
</head>

<body>


`<h1>Yelp Rating System</h1>`



<h2>Top 10 restaurants in zip code: {{zip_code}}</h2>

<table id="table" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Rank</th>
            <th>Restaurant Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td> 
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
var array = 
[["1","Kiku", "555 5th ave, New York, NY 11355", "212-111-2222"],
["2","Yamoto", "444 6th ave, New York, NY 11355", "212-888-9999"]
];
    var table = document.getElementById("table");

for(var i = 1; i <table.rows.length; i++)
{
    for(var j = 0; j< table.rows[i].cells.length; j++)
    {
      if(j==0)
        table.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML ='<a href="xyz.html">' +array[i-1][j]+ "</a>";
      else
         table.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML = array[i-1][j];
    }
}

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I see why the semi-colon was my main issue for not being able to see anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure what you mean by "how can I make column 1 of the table into a hyperlink for another HTML script." but I've managed to write up a solution for inserting the array into a table.

The HTML:

```
<table id="table" class="table">
  <tr><th>Rank</th><th>Restaurant Name</th><th>Address</th><th>Phone</th></tr>
</table>
```

The JS:

```
var values = new Array();
values[0] = ["1","Kiku", "555 5th ave, New York, NY 11355", "212-111-2222"];
values[1] = ["2","Yamoto", "444 6th ave, New York, NY 11355", "212-888-9999"];

var mixed = document.getElementById("table");

// IE7 only supports appending rows to tbody
var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");

// for each outer array row
for (var i = 0 ; i < values.length; i++) {
  var tr = document.createElement("tr");

  // for each inner array cell
  // create td then text, append
  for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
     var td = document.createElement("td");
     var txt = document.createTextNode(values[i][j]);
     td.appendChild(txt);
     tr.appendChild(td);
  }

   // append row to table
   // IE7 requires append row to tbody, append tbody to table
   tbody.appendChild(tr);
   mixed.appendChild(tbody);
}
```

Live example - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RyMdNN

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [
    ["1", "Kiku", "555 5th ave, New York, NY 11355", "212-111-2222"],
    ["2", "Yamoto", "444 6th ave, New York, NY 11355", "212-888-9999"]
  ],
  table = document.querySelector("#table tbody");

for (let i = 0, row = arr[i]; row = arr[i]; i++) {
  //Two main ways you can go from here: adding in the HTML by hand, or using nodes. I'm feeling lazy today.
  let row_html = "<tr>" + row.map(cell => "<td>" + cell + "</td>").join("") + "</tr>";
  //Please see notes in post
  table.innerHTML += row_html;
}

/*for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    var newRow = table.insertRow(table.length);
    for (var j = 0; j< array[i].length; j++)
    {
        var cell = newRow.insertCell[j];
        cell.innerHTML = array[i]][j];
    }
}*/
```

```html
`
<h1>Yelp Rating System</h1>`



<h2>Top 10 restaurants in zip code: {{zip_code}}</h2>

<table id="table" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Rank</th>
      <th>Restaurant Name</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <!--    <tr>            
                <td><a href="{{ url_for('restaurant', restaurant_info=11355 )}}">                   Restaurant x</a></td>
            </tr> 
        -->

  </tbody>
</table>
```

## Explanation

I apologize, I used some really weird notation in this post, so let me explain it.

First, I changed the `document.getElementById(...)` to be more correct -- see, you are getting the entire `<table>` element, when really you want the immediate parent of all the non-header rows, the `<tbody>` element. So I used `document.querySelector('#table tbody')` which works like a CSS selector, looking for a tbody element inside an element with an ID named #table. Note: `querySelector()` only returns the ***first*** match it finds. You shouldn't have multiple items with the ID of "table" *anyway*, but I've seen people try it before so you have official had this explained to you.

Next is a for loop, which is pretty mild all-in-all. However, I do some weird stuff. First let's talk about the sections of a for loop:

```
for ([initialization section] ; [true/false check to stop or continue] ; [thing ran at the end of every iteration of the loop])
```

In the initialization section, I initialize two variables,`i` and `row`. `i` is equal to 0, and row is equal to `arr[i]`, or the first element in the array we are looking at. Next, on every check I set `row = arr[i]` -- if `i` is outside of how many elements are in `arr` this will return undefined. Undefined is a falsey value, so the loop stops running. After every iteration, we just increase `i` by 1.

As for the stuff in the loop itself, you could also accomplish this by calling `document.createElement('tr')` and then doing something similar in mapping the currently used row's children to `<td>` elements using the DOM methods to append it, but in this case using strings was much faster for me. `arr.map(func)` returns a new array that has had the user-supplied function `func` run on every item. In my case, `func = cell=> "<td>"+cell+"</td>"` this is known as arrow notation, and I expect you to look that up. I then call `.join()` on each element to create one long string, which gets wrapped in `"<tr>"` and `"</tr>"`.

Let me know if you have any other questions I may have not answered in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation, but I'm afraid I can only give a useful vote to this since I could not understand everything even with your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array =
    [
        ["1", "Kiku", "555 5th ave, New York, NY 11355", "212-111-2222"],
        ["2", "Yamoto", "444 6th ave, New York, NY 11355", "212-888-9999"]
    ];

document.querySelector("#table tbody").innerHTML =
    array.map(tr => {
        return '<tr>' +
            tr.map(td => {
                return `<td>${td}</td>`
            }).join('') +
            '</tr>';
    }).join('');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link href="static/css/style2.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>The Top Ten Restaurants in {{zip_code}}</title>
</head>

<body>


    `
    <h1>Yelp Rating System</h1>`



    <h2>Top 10 restaurants in zip code: {{zip_code}}</h2>

    <table id="table" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Rank</th>
                <th>Restaurant Name</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right, please try this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="static/css/style2.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>The Top Ten Restaurants in {{zip_code}}</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Yelp Rating System</h1>
        <h2>Top 10 restaurants in zip code: {{zip_code}}</h2>
        <table id="table" class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Rank</th>
                    <th>Restaurant Name</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id = "records">
                <!-- record will be inserted here -->
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
<script>
    var array = [
                                ["1","Kiku", "555 5th ave, New York, NY 11355", "212-111-2222"],
                                ["2","Yamoto", "444 6th ave, New York, NY 11355", "212-888-9999"]
                            ];
    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    // console.log(array.length);
    var data = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        data += "<tr>";
        for(var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){
            if(j == 0){
                data += "<td><a href = '#'>" + array[i][j] + "</a></td>";
            }else{
                data += "<td>" + array[i][j] + "</td>";
            }
        }
        data += "</tr>";
    }
    var tbody = document.getElementById("records");
    tbody.innerHTML = data;
</script>
```